# How to loop animation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m trying to loop this animation but I don´t know why it does not work ?
I have 4 divs with differences images and I want to loop this to replay again and again.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval("comeon()", 2000);
});

function comeon() {
    var current = $(".current");
    var next = current.next();

    if (next.length == 0) {
        next = $(".current:first");
    }

    current.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
    next.css("opacity", "0.0").addClass("current").animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 500, function () {
        current.removeClass("previous");
        comeon();
    });
```

What I have done wrong ?

```
**UPDATE**



<div id="slider">
<div class="current" style="background-color:#F00;position:absolute; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
<div style="background-color:#00F;position:absolute; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
<div style="background-color:#0F0;position:absolute; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
<div style="background-color:#FF3;position:absolute; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>

</div><!-- End slider-->
```

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/7kt9z/6/

Comment: You are calling `comeon()` "recursively" from the animation callback already. Why do you think you would need `setInterval`? It should be enough to start the process with a single call at dom ready.

Comment: @Bergi good catch! Either remove the recursive call, or remove the interval.

Comment: Hello thanks for advice, I´m new with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
next = $("cur:first");
```

This is attempting to select an element like `<cur>`. Oops!

You want:

```
next = $(".current:first");
```

or

```
next = cur.first();
```

**Edit**

I finally understand what you need:

```
next = current.siblings().first();
```

Comment: Hello, thanks again. I have done it if you look at my if clause above.
But it loop only the first 2 divs. :S

Comment: I´m not used to jsfiddle. 

I can axplain you here. RIght now I have 4 divs with absolute position. And I´m trying to make slide show. The problem is when the last div show, the function will not loop again (I want none stop) Although I put the next = $(".current:first"); I believe I have placed it in the wrong way ?

Comment: I've updated with the answer I provided, and added the missing `}` at the end: http://jsfiddle.net/7kt9z/10/ It works fine.

Comment: Although it can be done without the interval as well: http://jsfiddle.net/7kt9z/17/

Comment: Yeahhhh this s what I want !
Can you axplain me something ?

Why siblings().first(); ? But not $("div.current:first");  ?


1.

Comment: Think of it like a tree. You have a container for the four divs. The divs are branches off the same container trunk. To select $('.current:first') will select only the one branch. You need to select the trunk first.

Comment: Hello again Joe, Why i does not work in dreamweaver ?   Why does it only work in js fiddle ?

Comment: Sorry I do not do dreamweaver. Good luck finding anyone here that does.

Comment: hmm but so strange...I will try to put it into the brwose and see.

maybe jQuery function ?

Answer (score 0):

setInterval needs to be used in a certain way.

You need to assign setInterval to a variable, and this assignment should be attached to an event.

```
var setIt;
$(window).load(function() {
    setIt = setInterval(comeOn, 1000);
});
```

Since you're using images, you can wait for all the images to load and then starting your slider (that's using the `load` event to assign `setInterval` to the variable `setIt`).

Also, do not wrap your function in qoutes in `setInterval`. Instead of:

```
setInterval("comeOn()", 1000)
```

Do this:

```
setInterval(comeOn, 1000)
```

I've got a working example here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rHzpL

Comment: Why would he need to assign the result of `setInterval` to any variable, he does not try to clear it anywhere?

Comment: This answer does not do anything for the issues at hand.